# Add 2 titles styles in Nivo Lightbox Jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, lightbox, title, nivo-slider

I need to add 2 different titles to customize each one of them in the Nivo Lightbox

Example:

http://prntscr.com/23o766

But it's look like is not possible, is there a way to put 2 titles on 1 image?

Or anyway to resolve this? also, I would love to be able to use the title as a link, but there are a lot of limitations.  thanks.

Code:

```
<a class="image image-full"  data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" href="nivo-lightbox/img/b/grey_antique_q_white_mortar_concave_finish_technique_view_b.jpg" title="Grey Antique Q White Mortar Concave Finish Technique View B">

<img id="sample_board_image" src="nivo-lightbox/img/s/grey_antique_q_white_mortar_concave_finish_technique_view_b.jpg" alt="Grey Antique Q White Mortar Concave Finish Technique View B"></img>
</a>
```

There's must be a way to add more than 1 style in the title or any other way to add that text in the overlay in the Lightbox.

I actually already tried the insertion of another html on the nivo lightbox, but it gives me a lot of trouble, the content is not showing properly, is there a way the content fits on the lightbox?

http://prntscr.com/23qm97

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by specifying an element id to the title attribute of the image for nivo slider and by specifying an element id to the href attribute of the link for nivo lightbox. The element id should point to an element with any content you wish.

**nivo lightbox**

In nivo lightbox it is possible to show html content by using the id element as value of the href attribute. So in order to display the image with the titles, the image and the titles should be part of the html content of the target element `#test` in the following example.

```
            <a href="#test" class="image image-full"  data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" href="nivo-lightbox/img/b/grey_antique_q_white_mortar_concave_finish_technique_view_b.jpg" title="Grey Antique Q White Mortar Concave Finish Technique View B">

<img id="sample_board_image" src="nivo-lightbox/img/s/grey_antique_q_white_mortar_concave_finish_technique_view_b.jpg" alt="Grey Antique Q White Mortar Concave Finish Technique View B"></img>
</a>
    <div id="test" style="display:none">this is from test

            <img id="sample_board_image" src="nivo-lightbox/img/s/grey_antique_q_white_mortar_concave_finish_technique_view_b.jpg" alt="Grey Antique Q White Mortar Concave Finish Technique View B"></img>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>a second <a href=#>title</a> as link</p>
        </div>
```

**nivo slider**

For example a slightly modified excerpt from the demo code of the nivo slider jquery plugin,

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
            <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. <br/>
                <b>and another title!!!!</b>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

So you may add any html content and class values to the elements to modify the titles as you require.

**EDIT**

In response to the latest comments, for nivo lightbox to fit the html content's image inside the lightbox and the screen resolution you need to specify attributes `height="100%"` and `width="100%"`.
A pretty rough example can be found below,

http://jsfiddle.net/45nAc/show/

*the first image is generated from html*

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="#test" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"><img alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_s.jpg"></a> <a title="Calm Before The Storm (One Shoe Photography Ltd.)" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3824/9041440555_2175b32078_b.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"><img alt="" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3824/9041440555_2175b32078_s.jpg"></a> <a title="Lambs Valley (JMImagesonline.com)" href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2870/8985207189_01ea27882d_b.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"><img alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2870/8985207189_01ea27882d_s.jpg"></a> <a title="Grasmere Lake (Phil 'the link' Whittaker (gizto29))" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3677/8962691008_7f489395c9_b.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"><img alt="" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3677/8962691008_7f489395c9_s.jpg"></a></p>
    <div id="test" style="display:none">
            <img width="100%" height="100%" alt="" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_b.jpg"/>
        <div class="titles">
            <p> this is a title1 <br/>
                this is a <a href=#>title2</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;       /*background:url('http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_b.jpg');*/
}

#test .titles {
    text-align:center;
}


.nivo-lightbox-theme-default .nivo-lightbox-ajax, .nivo-lightbox-theme-default .nivo-lightbox-inline{
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Be prepared to play around with css and achieve anything you require.

Comment: That's correct, for the Nivo Slider. I'm asking for the Nivo Lightbox

Comment: @user2984054 you are correct i updated the answer and also left the info related to nivo slider in case a future visitor finds it useful.

Comment: I actually already tried the insertion of another html on the nivo lightbox, but it gives me a lot of trouble, the content is not showing properly, is there a way the content fits on the lightbox?

Comment: @user2984054 updated the answer with an example. Basically you can modify the html content any way you like by using a nice html structure and css.